# Is it possible to get a field from query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Essentially im trying to insert a result from a query into another database than the one where the query orginated from. Im trying to figure out if A) im going at this in the the right direction and B) if this is even possible.

```
try {
  let array = await cursor.toArray()
  console.log(array)
  const setCompany = await account.updateOne({
    _id: ObjectId(userId)
  },
  {$set: {"companyName": array}})
} catch(e){
  console.error(`Unable to insert: ${e}`)
}
```

`conosle.log result = [ { companyName: "name" } ]`

I've tried to `JSON.stringify` and remove the result of the array and tried ways to remove everything but just the "name" as that is what im trying to get in order to set it in the other document.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the contents of `array`? What is printed by that second line?

Comment: @user20042973 array is [ { companyName: "Name" } ] the console error doenst print as this will update just the update will be "companyName": " [ { companyName: "Name" }" in the mongoDb

Comment: Change `array` in your update to `array[0].companyName`.  Alternatively change the original query to a `findOne` and then you won't have to have `[0]` in the update

Comment: @user20042973 Thanks I tried that earlier only with just array[0] that has solved the problem! Thank you for your time, good sir!